# Check multiple file paths exists before running script

Tags: powershell

I need to check that I have all files before running the rest of my powershell script.
What is the best way to go through the below code and after it has found each file required, continue with the rest of my script. Or if any of the files are not found, I send an email alert along with exiting the script.

```
# collect log one
if (Test-Path $logone) {
    $one = Import-Csv -Path $logone
    Write-Host "Log one found"
}
else {
    #Send email "Log one not found!"
    Write-Host "Log one not found!"
}
# collect log two
if (Test-Path -Path $logtwo) {
    $two = Import-Csv -Path $logtwo 
    Write-Host "Log two found"
}
else {
    #Send email "Log two not found!"
    Write-Host "Log two not found!"
}
# collect log three data
if (Test-Path -Path $logthree) {
    $three = Import-Csv -Path $logthree 
    Write-Host "Log three found"
}
else {
    #Send email "Log three not found!"
    Write-Host "Log three not found!"
}
```

Would I just add the following code below what I have:

```
if (Test-Path $logone) -and (Test-Path $logtwo) -and (Test-Path $logthree) {
# continue with the rest of my code
}
else {
Write-Host "Script exited with error"
Exit
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I would put all the paths into a list/array and loop over them. If any failed, change a variable to not continue.

Comment: you may want to look at the `*-FileCatalog` cmdlets. this looks likely to do what you want >>> `Get-Help Test-FileCatalog -Online` <<<

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you sure you want all logs to be present to execute your code or do you want to execute your code for each log present?

Comment: @Thomas - I need to combine the data contained in all logs, before running the rest of my script, if some of the log data is not found. Then the report will not be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on I.T Delinquent's answer here an example of how to achieve this:

```
$logOne = "C:\Temp\log1"
$logTwo = "C:\Temp\log2"
$logThree = "C:\Temp\log3"
$mandatoryLogs = $logOne,$logTwo,$logThree
$errors = @()
$count = 0
$logs = @{}

foreach($log in $mandatoryLogs){
    $count++
    if(Test-Path $log){
        $logs["log$count"] = Import-Csv -Path $log
        Write-Host "Log $count found!"
    }else{
        $errors += "$log is missing"
    }
}

if($errors){
    $body = @"
Dear Admin,

The following errors occured: $($errors | Out-String)

Regards
"@
    try{
        Send-MailMessage -Body $body # -To -From etc etc
    }catch{
        throw $_
    }
    throw "Quiting because of errors, mail has been sent"
}else{
    Write-Host "Continuing script" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Next you can access each of the logs in the following way:

```
$logs['log1']
```

Or:

```
Write-Host "$($logs['log3'].randomPropertyWhichExistsInTheCSV)"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this, I will test the code and let you know how it goes. ;-)